# How can I determine what date I upvoted a post on?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, up-votes

Is there a way to determine what exact date I upvoted a post on?

It would be very useful when hovering over a previously voted on post if I could see a little popup with the date I cast the vote.

Now that I have hundreds (thousands?) of answers upvoted, it's very difficult to know when I upvoted them.

**EDIT**:  having the date I upvoted an answer would be very useful, please see this:

[image]
Just telling me I have already upvoted the answer does not give me anything useful, since the color of the arrow already tells me this.

Comment: Profile --> Activity --> Votes

Comment: This seems like information that would be most suited for the timeline, especially since many users can't hover (eg mobile users).

Comment: Without any information as to why it would be so helpful to you, it’s less likely that the problem will get much momentum in leading to a change in the system.  Why do you need to remember this?  I would actually just create my own app (or use a notebook) to retain this information; especially if I had a habit of tracking chronology, etc. in these pointer-tastic ways.

Answer (score 8):

In some situations – namely, when your vote is locked in and the post hasn't been edited since you voted – you can click the upvote button again, and a popup will tell you when you voted:

[image: Example screenshot of locked-in vote notification]

You can see all your votes [in your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes), but it might take a lot of time to search through it. You could first search for the page in your browser history and find out when you visited it, and use that to navigate through the vote list.

Comment: i was hoping for something much easier.    ever since i started using stack overflow & stack exchange, if there is anything i do not immediately remember, i search for it and look for any upvoted question/answer.  right or wrong, i have come to depend on it, perhaps too much so.  and there are situations i upvoted two answers at different times, which is why it might be useful to quickly determine which answer was the most recently upvoted.

Comment: @edwardsmarkf The first option seems pretty easy to me. The only caveat is that if you're really concerned about the original time you voted, clicking the vote button again risks causing that information to be lost if the post has been edited. I have an idea for a userscript but I'm not very good with javascript. I might give it a try if no one else does. [1/2]

Comment: Basically, it will append a small button next to all pressed vote buttons. Clicking any of the added buttons will search for the post id in the `users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote&page=n` (or `sort=downvote`) pages to get the timestamp (similar to how [this userscript](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/ReviewFinder.user.js), by [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene), works). [2/2]